# BigQuery Data Transfer Service Error

Tags: google-bigquery

I had the below errors with the BigQuery Data Transfer Service. Has anyone encountered these errors before?

- Error 1
  [image: Error 1]
- Error 2
  [image: Error 2]

Comment: Please post the errors as text rather than as images.  This is so that they are searchable, and also easier for someone to do searches with.

Comment: [This error](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-troubleshooting#doubleclick_for_publishers_transfer_issues) can appear if using an [unsupported delimiter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/doubleclick-publisher-transfer). Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Did you request a custom schema for your data transfer files? The field should be "Campaign ID" per the documentation: 
https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/dtv2/reference/file-format

If so, it can be resolved by asking customer support that helped with the original setup to use standard values.